# Read NetworkStream with UTF8 Encoding

Tags: c#, character-encoding, buffer, networkstream

I'm trying to send JSON-objects via Network Streams. I'm able to send one message and deserialize it but after reciving it my **While loop** exits. I think it has to do with **NetworkStream.Read** expecting fixed byte size encoding (ASCII), but I'm using UTF8 with varying byte sizes.
Is there some way I can make **NetworkStream.Read** read the correct amount of bytes?

Function for sending data:

```
        private void SendMessage(TcpClient client, string message)
    {
            stream = client.GetStream();

            var data = new MessageModel
            {
                RequestType = "Message",
                Name = clientName,
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Message = message
            };

            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            byte[] jsonData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
            stream.Write(jsonData, 0, jsonData.Length);
        }
    }
```

Function for receiving data:

```
    private void RecieveMessages(TcpClient client)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) > 0)
        {
            string jsonString = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);
            MessageModel message = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MessageModel>(jsonString);

            Console.WriteLine($"RequestType: {message?.RequestType}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {message?.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Date: {message?.Date}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {message?.Message}");
        }

        client.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected.");
    }
```

**Solved:** As Jon Skeet pointed out this had nothing to do with encoding. I accidently closed client stream when writing messages.

Comment: "I think it has to do with NetworkStream.Read expecting fixed byte size encoding (ASCII)" - what has led you to that conclusion? It sounds like the writing side has closed the stream, otherwise `stream.Read` wouldn't return 0. (Note that assuming you'll get a complete message in a single read is really dangerous... there are multiple approaches to using a stream for discrete messages, such as "one message before closing the stream", or length-prefixing, or a delimiter (e.g. a line break) that can never occur otherwise.)

Comment: You are correct, had nothing to do with UTF8 having varying byte sizes, I accidentally closed the connection after writing. Thank you!

Comment: Side note: you have a fatal flaw in your read logic. There is no guarantee that a single send by the other side will result in a single receive. They may be split or joined as seen fit into multiple packets or buffers. You need a message framing protocol, see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html Consider using an existing protocol like HTTP rather than rolling your own.